# Error in Counting Non-Zero Pixels

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I would like to count the non-zero pixel of an image without converting the image into a Numpy array. Here is the piece of code I have

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import cv

image = Image.new('1', (100, 100)) 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse((20, 20, 80, 80), fill ='white')
non_zeros = cv.CountNonZero(image)
```

However, when I run this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: CvArr argument 'arr' must be IplImage, CvMat or CvMatND. Use fromarray() to convert numpy arrays to CvMat or cvMatND
```

How can I solve this problem? either by continuing with `cv.CountNonZero` or any other way which is computationally cheap and efficient.

Comment: Why are you avoiding numpy conversion? Any special reasons? Numpy buffers are the way OpenCV interfaces with python.

Comment: @imaluengo Are they computationally efficient? When my image size gets bigger the computational bottleneck for my code would be conversion to Numpy array.

Comment: Numpy library is writtnen in C. I doubt that the bottleneck is the conversion to numpy. I work with 3D images `1000x1000x500`, and creating an empty (or filled) array of that size in numpy is instant. The bottleneck will be the operations you make on it.

Comment: @imaluengo I figured out that the bottleneck is using `np.count_nonzero(img_to_np_array)`. Is there any faster way to count nonzeros of a numpy array?

Comment: You can pass the numpy array to OpenCV. But anyway, `np.count_nonzero` works at C speed, I doubt you are going to get much more speedup. How big is your image? And how *slow* is in numpy?